# Does C++ ABI specify how vTable and RTTI information should exist?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, vtable, abi

Popular implementation like GCC/VC uses the first size_t space of an polymorphic object as a pointer, pointing to a vtable structure. Is this part of latest C++ ABI?

How about RTTI implementation, does C++ ABI specify how to implement?
Thanks

Comment: as far as i know, c++ doesnt have a uniform c++ ABI. i think you must read it from compiler to compiler. but iam not a compiler guy.

Comment: The standard doesn't specify an implementation of virtual functions or RTTI. As such, no ABI is mandated.

Comment: I don't think it's the first `size_t` space. It's probably the first `void*` space, or perhaps the first `intptr_t` space.

Comment: There isn't even an official ANSI or ISO **C** ABI!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the C++ standard does not specify how any of this should be implemented. There is no single C++ ABI.

Comment: @Yakk: So be it :)